# Pandas resample and ffill leaves NaN at the end

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, resampling

I want to up-sample a series from weekly to daily frequency by forward filling the result.

If the last observation of my original series is `NaN`, I would have expected this value to be replaced by the previous valid value, but instead it remains as `NaN`.

**SETUP**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

all_dates = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', freq='W-WED', periods=4)

ts = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=all_dates[:3])
ts[all_dates[3]] = np.nan

ts
Out[16]: 
2018-01-03    1.0
2018-01-10    2.0
2018-01-17    3.0
2018-01-24    NaN
Freq: W-WED, dtype: float64
```

**RESULT**

```
ts.resample('B').ffill() 

ts.resample('B').ffill()
Out[17]: 
2018-01-03    1.0
2018-01-04    1.0
2018-01-05    1.0
2018-01-08    1.0
2018-01-09    1.0
2018-01-10    2.0
2018-01-11    2.0
2018-01-12    2.0
2018-01-15    2.0
2018-01-16    2.0
2018-01-17    3.0
2018-01-18    3.0
2018-01-19    3.0
2018-01-22    3.0
2018-01-23    3.0
2018-01-24    NaN
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```

While I was expecting the last value to be 3 as well.

Does anyone has an *explanation* of this behaviour?

Comment: you are not replacing `nulls` here. For that use `df['B'].fillna(ffill)`

Comment: your suggestion gives exactly the same result: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html

Comment: @FLab `2018-01-24 ` is a  `NaN` so try `ts.ffill().resample('B').ffill()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of resample and `ffill`is simply to propagate forward from the first day of the week - if the first day of the week is `NaN`, that's what gets filled forward. For example:

```
ts.iloc[1] = np.nan
ts.resample('B').ffill()

2018-01-03    1.0
2018-01-04    1.0
2018-01-05    1.0
2018-01-08    1.0
2018-01-09    1.0
2018-01-10    NaN
2018-01-11    NaN
2018-01-12    NaN
2018-01-15    NaN
2018-01-16    NaN
2018-01-17    3.0
2018-01-18    3.0
2018-01-19    3.0
2018-01-22    3.0
2018-01-23    3.0
2018-01-24    NaN
Freq: B, dtype: float64
```

In most cases, propagating from the previous week's data would *not* be desired behaviour. If you'd like to use previous weeks' data in the case of missing values in the original (weekly) series, just `fillna` on that first with `ffill`.

Answer (score 2):

`resample()` returns `DatetimeIndexResampler`

You need to return the original pandas `Series`.

You can use `asfreq()` method to do it, before filling the `Nan` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html.

So, this should work:

`ts.resample('B').asfreq().ffill()`